# How do I use JQuery Validation in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to use the JQuery Validation's "addClassRules" method in my ASP.NET MVC application.

In my master page I'm including the following files...

```
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMVCAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMVCValidation.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-validate.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm not sure which are actually required so I've added them all:)  Potential problem area?

In my View I've got a simple textbox element which I'm trying to add the "required" validation via the Class attribute.  I've got dynamic forms and my end goal is to specify different validation rules in the Class attribute.  So for now I'm got something like this...

```
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FieldEntry.Response.TextBoxValue, new { @class = "cRequired" } )%>
```

then at the end of my View I'm including the following script which I though was suppose to hook up the Class name to a validation rule.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready( function()
{
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
      cRequired: {
        required: true
      }
    });
})
</script>
```

Seems like a straightforward example but the problem I am having is that I keep getting an error that **jQuery.validator is null or not an object**.  This refers to the first line of the the ready() function in the script above.

Any help / suggestions?

Comment: Are you including jQuery later in the page possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem should be somewhere at including the validator plugin because `jQuery.validator` should not be null if you include the file correctly.

1. Have you downloaded [**this** validator plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and put the `jquery.validate.js` file in the `Scripts` folder?
2. In the page in which your are using validation: Is this page really using **that** master page?
3. In the master page: Is the include of the validation plugin `script` **before** the `ContentPlaceHolder`?

Comment: Well...  it was infront of the ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" but not the "TitleContent".  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the *jQuery.validator is null or not an object* error was caused by including the `jquery.js` library **twice in the same page** and using **a different version** of `jquery.js` in each case.